Short film about a Japan-obsessed wife who makes her husband a bento lunch every day
I believe the short film (live action) was in French and relatively recent, probably from within the last 5 years. The story was about a middle-aged husband and wife in a relatively unhappy marriage. The wife has taken up an obsession with all things Japanese in an effort to revitalize their marriage, but the husband is not really on board with this. He works each day at some sort of waste processing plant or factory.
The wife lovingly prepares cute little bento boxes for her husband's lunch each day, but he secretly discards them at work, buying sandwiches instead. The husband also becomes attracted to a young male co-worker, who eventually offers to perform a DIY nipple piercing.

 When the wife eventually finds out that her husband is not eating her bento, they have an argument. The next day, she places an implied-to-be-poisoned sandwich in her husband's lunch instead, which he eats and suffers a very surreal death, cut with scenes of the wife peacefully performing a traditional Japanese dance.

Does anyone know the name of this film?

Bento Monogatari (2010), a Belgian short film. It's in Dutch.

A woman tries to put some new life into her failed marriage by delving
  into the world of Japanese pop-culture. Every morning, she prepares a
  cute Japanese lunchbox (bento) for her husband, Frank, who works in
  the waste collection center. Frank is more interested in his
  beautiful, young, male colleague and secretly throws his lunchbox
  away before anyone sees it.

Full film (27min approx.) on Youtube, with English subtitles:




Ah, that's definitely the one!
